# Automatically, periodically check for shiny app errors

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have many (like 30) shiny apps deployed on shiny server (open source version). It happens from time to time that when I (or one of my colleagues) update one of the packages, some of the apps stop working. I wonder if instead of checking all the apps manually every time we change anything, there is some way to perform the checks automatically? An ideal solution would be to have a script that is run daily (hourly?) checking if each app can be loaded and if not, an email is send. I am not taking about small errors here. More about app not loading at all due to in ex. some function missing. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I recently learned about shinytest. This could help https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/